# [: =: unary operator expected erorr

Tags: linux, bash, centos7, unary-operator

I can't figure out what did wrong in this part :

```
echo "Which Password policy you would like to select: 1) basic12, 2) basic16, 3) comp8 (enter: 1, 2, or 3)"

sudo read -p input

if [ $input = "1" ]; then

    echo "Definition basic12 := (enforce new_pwd (min length 12) New Password must be at least 12 charactors long!)."

fi
```

but i get this error :  line 3: [: =: unary operator expected

which in my scrip line 3 is this part:  if [ "$input" = "1" ]; then

would anyone help me what please?

Comment: Do you have quotes around `$input` or not in that?

Comment: if `$input` is undefined then your test becomes: `[ = "1" ]` which will generate the error you're receiving; place $input` in double quotes (eg, `[ "$input" = "1" ]`) and you should get past the error message, but then you'll need to figure out why `$input` is empty/undefined

Comment: - Shawn  and  - markp thank you , yes i did't put quotes, i did it and that error gone, but i expected after i put "1" as input my scrip show this :  "Definition basic12 := (enforce new_pwd (min length 12) New Password must be at least 12 charactors long!)."  on my screen as outpt of my scrip but nothing happening , would u please let me know what part did i wrong again ?

Comment: The `sudo` command will be run as a separate process, and it will perhaps run read in a subshell, but the value it reads will never be available to your script.  Why do you think you need superuser privileges to read from standard input?  Get rid of the `sudo` and things will work better, though always quoting variable is also valuable advice.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you and anyone who helps me to learn even one thing also, I deleted the "Sudo" as you said but, still, when I run my scrip I expected after I put "1" as input, my scrip shows this: "Definition basic12:= (enforce new_pwd (min length 12) New Password must be at least 12 characters long!)." on my screen as output of my scrip but nothing happening, would u please let me know what part did I wrong again?

Comment: IIRC, the `-p` option to Bash `read` specifies the prompt in the next argument.  If so, you’ve not specified a variable name.  Maybe you should repeat `input` on the command, or perhaps drop the `-p`instead.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank u I did what u said but didn't work for me